# Pre to Post Repeated measures for categorical dependent variable and more than one independent variables both continues and catgorical

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, predictive-models

I am doing Prenatal (before delivery) and Postnatal (after delivery) depression assessment (2 time points).
Dependent variable is Depressed/Non depressed mother on a measure of depression.
When as there a  number of predictor variables both continues and categorical in nature.
Clearly speaking I am using 2 questionnaires at 2 time points: i) dependent variable is dichotomous, ii) dependent variable has continuous predictors.

Can i use Generalized estimating equation?
What exactly constitutes repeated measures logistic regression?